# How to move a view in circle with onTouch in android

Tags: java, android, animation

I am facing a problem in an project. I have a activity in which i had create a Round shape layout with Framelayout. My problem is that i don;t know how to implement items in layout in round shape. and move the items with ontouch event and when the items come on the specific postion a toast display or alert dialog show. I am attach the image for demo.

[image]

Comment: Any news, Pardeep?

Comment: sorry bro , this code is not working. i want when user touch the circle the circle also move forword or backword. and when the  user stop scrolling on that time which number is near the red box that activity will open.   But thanks for giving me this suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a **View** that implements the **onTouch event with a Drag feature**.

1) In order to give your view the round shape, you need to create a **file that contains those specifications** in the drawable folder.

Create your **drawable/your_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

2) In your View that you want to make round, set the background to that same drawable like

```
<YourView 
    android:id="@+id/your_id"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/your_circle"/>
```

And then, apply the following procedure to the Activity

```
public class DraggableActivity extends Activity {

    float dX;
    float dY;
    int lastAction;
    View.OnTouchListener touchListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drag_view_layout);

        // 1 - Create the touch listener
        touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
                        view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            Toast.makeText(DraggableView.this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 2 - Add a reference to your view that already is stated on the layout
        final View dragView = findViewById(R.id.your_id);

        // 3 - Attac the the TouchListener to your view
        dragView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Regards,